# Getting out of closure Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm building this program to use during Trivial Pursuit for questions. I'm having trouble getting the size of the dictionary to be stored in the `size` variable from the function. I have tried every way you can store a variable but I always get the value of zero.

```
var size:Int = Int()

@IBOutlet var questionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var answerLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func answerButton(sender: AnyObject) {


}

func getSize() {

    self.size = scienceDictionary.count

}

var scienceDictionary = ["What is the chemical process that converts sugar into alcohol?": "Fermentation",
    "Where in your body would you find you hippocampus?": "Brain",]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(size)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should just make `size` a computed property:

```
var size: Int {
    return scienceDictionary.count
}
```

and your `getSize()` function will become superfluous.

Comment: That works but I also but I also want a random number that uses the size of the dictionary to choose the random number but the random number keeps changing and need it to be static. But I can't declare it outside of any function in the view controller

Comment: @user3103854: Your code doesn't mention random numbers. Your question should specify what you actually want, rather than some completely different problem.

Answer (score 0):

By default, your `size` variable is 0. Based on the code you show, `getSize()` is never called, so `size` never changes.

However, I recommend not doing what you want to do. Instead of using a size variable, simply type `scienceDictionary.count` wherever you want to find the size. This is much clearer and requires a lot less extra work.

Comment: That would work but I'm trying to randomize it with a random number but I can't store the size of the dictionary or the randomNumber variable in the ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling `getSize()` anywhere. You should call it for the code inside to be executed, like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getSize()
    print(size)
}
```